# Define roles in a bundle config

Tags: symfony

I have some questions about roles that I'm trying to understand a long time:

**1.** We have some bundles that we use in couple of projects. We would like to define roles in a bundle config, so that we do not copy roles into the role_hierarchy in `security.yml`. Is there any clean way to do it?

My first idea was to import them into role_hierarchy like this:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:                             ROLE_USER, ROLE_TRANSLATOR
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:                       ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_NOT_APPROVED_USER:                 ROLE_USER
    ROLE_TRANSLATOR:                        ROLE_USER
    "%base_bundle.role.hierarchy%"
```

This of course doesn't work. Is there any possibility to do it this way(merge arrays in yaml)?

My other idea was to store roles in DB, but in my opinion it's overkill, because we have no dynamic roles. Everything is static.

Is there any workaround to achieve what I try to do? Or is it a good idea to define it in a bundle?

**2.** I use roles as permissions (`ROLE_POST_EDIT`, `ROLE_POST_DELETE`, ...) and voters to deny or approve access to the resource. So at the end there are a tons of roles. Is it a good idea to mix roles with permissions? If not what is the best practise?

**EDIT:** I feel the difference between `ROLE_POST_EDIT` and `ROLE_USER` or `ROLE_ADMIN`. User has `ROLE_USER` because he is user. But user has "permission `ROLE_EDIT_POST`" to be able to edit a post. In my opinion there is a difference between. Anyway should I care about this difference or is there any other practise how to do?

Comment: Have you tried that way:
```role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:                       ROLE_ADMIN
    ROLE_NOT_APPROVED_USER:                 ROLE_USER
    ROLE_TRANSLATOR:                        ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:                            [ROLE_USER, ROLE_TRANSLATOR]```

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, but checkout this: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/07/symfony2-security-creating-dynamic-roles-using-roleinterface/

Comment: @rokas The problem is of course that I am passing array parameter `"%base_bundle.role.hierarchy%"` to the role hierarchy. But the question is not about it.
@B.Assem Thank you for the link. I have already seen it, but probably not think too much about it. In fact that can be one way to go. So I could write a Role class and pass bundle parameters into it.

Comment: There is also this article about YAML inheritance: https://web.archive.org/web/20130213112648/http://blog.101ideas.cz/posts/dry-your-yaml-files.html and this one http://atechie.net/2009/07/merging-hashes-in-yaml-conf-files/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. We have some bundles that we use in couple of projects. We would like to define roles in a bundle config, so that we do not copy roles into the role_hierarchy in security.yml. Is there any clean way to do it?

You can use [Prepended Extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html) to "prepend" configuration of another extension:

```php
class AcmeHelloExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    // ...

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->prependExtensionConfig('security', [
            'role_hierarchy' => [
                'ROLE_ADMIN' => ...
                ...
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

> 2. I use roles as permissions (ROLE_POST_EDIT, ROLE_POST_DELETE, ...) and voters to deny or approve access to the resource. So at the end there are a tons of roles. Is it a good idea to mix roles with permissions? If not what is the best practise?

A small misconfusion here: The roles you define with `role_hierarchy` are *not* related to the things you pass to `isGranted()`. You're passing attributes to `isGranted()`. Unfortunately, for the RoleHierarchyVoter, symfony decided to make the attributes similair to the role name (that is, if the role name starts with `ROLE_`).

Voters vote on permissions, or attributes as they are called. So it's perfectly valid and good practice to have many permissions in `isGranted()`.

However, I recommend not to start them with `ROLE_*`. These attributes are checked by the RoleVoter/RoleHierarchyVoter. Name them e.g. `POST_EDIT`, `POST_DELETE`:

```
if ($this->isGranted('POST_EDIT', $post)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hadn't known about prependesExtensions. It fits well to my use case.
I probably haven't explained it well. I have ROLE_POST_EDIT role. Only user with this role(and even with another role) can edit a post. And then I have attributes("edit","show") that I "pass to the voters" isGranted('edit', $post). 
But ROLE_POST_EDIT looks more as a permission to me(not in terminology of voters). Administrator has ROLE_ADMIN because he is admin. User has ROLE_USER because he is user. But user can have a "permission ROLE_POST_EDIT" to be able to edit posts. Should I care about it?

Comment: @user254319 ah, no. Check out https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html . You would create voters that determine whether one is allowed to edit a post. This voter will check whether e.g. it is an admin or the original owner of the post. I always recommend having one role per user: The user's role on the site.

Comment: One role to one user make sense to me, but it's too static in my case. We have let's say about 200 parts where the user can go if he has appropriate permission. And it should be possible change user or group permissions everytime. How to do it then? In our case a lot of voters looks like if ($user->hasRole('ROLE_LIST_POSTS' && $attribute === 'list') return ...GRANTED; and only a few where we check if the user is somehow connected with resource(e.g. owner), so the acl seems overcomplicated for this use cases.

Comment: I should probably make one table called `Permission` with connection to the `Group` table. It's one solution. Or is there another better one? I've seen some questions similar to this, but haven't found a good answer. I am for sure doing something that is possible(because is working in my case), but mixing two different thinks. And in my experience more people do the same.

Comment: @user254319 you *might* be interested in [ACL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl.html)